# Do Facebook posts like in swift

Tags: swift, facebook, facebook-like

I am able to like Facebook pages using `FBSDKLikeControl` with that page url. Some thing like this.

```
let likeButton = FBSDKLikeControl()
likeButton.objectID = "https://www.facebook.com/FacebookDevelopers"
likeButton.center = self.view.center;
view.addSubview(likeButton)
```

However I am not able to do like on posts by giving `likeButton.objectID = "1802945816386201_17414239392050"`

Can we like user posts, photo using Facebook API ?

Comment: You can like a posts by using Facebook Graph Api

Comment: @Raymond you can not like _as_ a user any more via API.

Comment: "Note: as of Nov 17, 2016 we changed the behavior of publishing likes and only support this action with Page Access Tokens." https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.10/object/likes#publish

As @CBroe said you cannot "Like" as a user.